# How do I set up a link to a WMSLayer in JOSM? URL works in QGIS but not JOSM

Tags: wms, josm

I have a publicly available WMS link that I'm trying to use as a layer in JOSM. It comes from http://dggs.alaska.gov/

http://maps.dggs.alaska.gov/arcgis/services/apps/Lidar_Hillshade/MapServer/WMSServer

When I load it in QGIS it connects to the server and there is a list of layers that I can add. When I try to load it in JOSM, there are no options of choosing layers, just inputting the link. I use 'add rectified layer' and enter the URL but no tiles are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been trying to add it through Imagery>Rectified Images.

But the solution was through Imagery Preferences. From there I chose the +WMS on the bottom-right and then chose the layer I wanted. Then I hit OK. Went back to the main screen, chose Imagery tab and my WMS layer was in the drop-down.